# Error array dimension missing

Tags: java, arrays, dimensions

I keep getting array dimension missing

```
public static Planet[] readPlanets(String filename) {

    allPlanets = new Planet[];
    In in = new In (filename);
    int nplanets = in.readInt();
    double radius = in.readDouble();
    for (int i = 0; i < allPlanets.length; i++) {
        double pxxPos = in.readDouble();
        double pyyPos = in.readDouble();
        double pxxVel = in.readDouble();
        double pyyVel = in.readDouble();
        double pmass = in.readDouble();
        String pimgFileName = in.readString();
    }
    return allPlanets;
}
```

Planet has six dimensions, and I have an array of multiple planets

Comment: Please post code as *text*, not as a screenshot. It would help if you'd show how you've declared `allPlanets`, as I doubt that it actually has 6 dimensions...

Comment: Looks like `Planet` has ONE dimension, maybe with six elements?

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare size of the array before you can use it's `length` attribute.

For example:

```
allPlanets = new Planet[6];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array, you have to specify the size. I strongly suspect you want:

```
In in = new In(filename);
int nPlanets = in.readInt();
allPlanets = new Planet[nPlanets];
```

Note that it's odd that you're assigning to a field and returning the reference from the method. It would be more usual to do one *or* the other, e.g. use a local variable:

```
Planet[] planets = new Planet[nPlanets];
...

return planets;
```

And then assign to the field in the calling code:

```
allPlanets = readPlanets(...);
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. but all planets is an array of planets and each planet has six dimensions. plants is the total number of planets in the array